# Send alert if item has already been selected

Tags: angular

```
public onSubmit(id, product_name){

var data = {
   id,
   product_name
};

this.items.push(data);
localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.items));
var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('id');
var retrieveObject = JSON.parse(retrieverObject);
if (retrieveObject == id) {
    alert('test');
}
}
```

I want to check if the value has already been submitted. This is part of a shopping cart application in which the product quantity will be updated if the product has already been chosen.

Comment: Are you getting the id and is localStorage set with the id property?

Comment: I edited my post to show how the items were getting set in response to your comment.

Comment: getItem is probably an array. I will have to check it when I get home from work.

Comment: getItems seems to be getting the products ID and not the items ID. But when I use getItem(items.id), it returns null.

Comment: When I use localStorage.getItem('MyDataStorageKey'), it returns:

[{"id":0,"product_name":"Adult Male Bike"},{"id":0,"product_name":"Adult Male Bike"}]

so I tried 'MyDataStorageKey.id' and 'MyDataStorageKey[id]' but they both returned null.

Comment: getItems('id') is definitely getting the products ID and not the items ID.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('MyDataStorageKey[0].id'); returns null

Comment: localStorage.getItem('MyDataStorageKey["id"]') returns null

Comment: So local storage is not set , please check your browser dev tools --> applications --> local storage to confirm if its set or not , if not set it through localStorage.setItem('key', value)

Comment: Local storage is set.

Comment: If it is set then it should not return null , as you told ocalStorage.getItem('MyDataStorageKey.indexOf("id")'); also returns null. Can you share a snap of your localStorage

Comment: My local storage looks like this:

Comment: Storage {MyDataStorageKey: "[{"id":1,"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":1,…_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5}]", firebase:host:cart-64d3f.firebaseio.com: ""s-usc1c-nss-239.firebaseio.com"", id: "2", product_name: "{"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":2,"product_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5}", …}
0: "0"
MyDataStorageKey: "[{"id":1,"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":1,"product_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5},{"id":1,"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":1,"product_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5}]"

Comment: firebase:host:cart-64d3f.firebaseio.com: ""s-usc1c-nss-239.firebaseio.com""
id: "2"
items: "[{"id":1,"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":1,"product_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5}]"
length: 8
product_name: "{"thumbnail":"product-2.gif","quantity":2,"product_name":"Adult Female Bike","product_price":20.5}"
this.items: "[]"

Comment: All of these return null:
var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('items["id"]');
  var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('items[0].id');
  var retrieverObject =  localStorage.getItem('items[{"id"}]');

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('items');
var retrieveObject = JSON.parse(retrieverObject);
 
if(retrieveObject === null) {
  console.log('no tasks')
} else {
  retrieveObject.forEach(function(el){
   alert("This is the storage id " + el.id);
   if (el.id == id){
   alert(el.id + " same ");
   }
  });
}
```